# SQL Prepared statement reuse in plan cache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, plan-cache, prepared-statement, query-performance

I'm working on minimising our plan cache usage, and I've read a lot around Adhoc queries and how we can parameterize and reuse rather than having many single use plans.

I'm not seeing as much information out there about the prepared plan reuse.  We have around 100gb of RAM dedicated to our production box, and 90% of our plan cache is divided into ~10% Single Use Adhoc, ~35% Plan stubs Adhoc and 36% Single Use Prepared.

So, I am basically trying to understand what prepared really means.

I believe the plans exist only for the duration of the connection, but I can see that many of the plans are duplicates similar to this:

```
(@bitValid BIT OUTPUT)IF(SELECT COUNT(pkItemID) FROM vwValidateDetail WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE fkInvoiceID = 43630155) > 0 BEGIN SET @bitValid = 1 END
```

Similarly, there are UPDATE statements where there are many plans for the same type - where one part is parameterized and the rest of the query isn't.

```
(@ElementValue nvarchar(4000))UPDATE ImportInterfaceSub Set [sub1] = @ElementValue WHERE [ID] = 18926954
```

Even if these queries are short lived, is there a better way I can parameterize the queries to re-use for memory?

The sql in question lives in a stored procedure which looks parameterized already IE:

```
UPDATE ImportInterfaceSub Set [sub1] = NULL WHERE [ID] = @id
```

Is this just a factor of how the engine operates, or is there a gain to be re-writing prepared queries as well as the single-use adhoc queries?

Comment: If the application code is based on the `.NET Framework`, [this article](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2018/12/Prepared-T-SQL-Statements.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but it's actually an MS Access application.  It's too costly to have the developers review and fix this instead of writing new code unfortunately.